# log in page fails at form tag definitions

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code snippet

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'process_login'%>
   Username: <%= text_field "user", "fullname" %>&#x00A;
   Password: <%= password_field "user", "password" %>&#x00A;
   <%= submit_tag %>
<%= end_form_tag %>
```

that is used as an index.rb page to log in my system.
The controller index function looks like this

```
def index    
    @user=MyEmployee.new
    @user.fullname=params[:fullname]
    @user.password=params[:password]
end
```

The error is

```
undefined local variable or method `end_form_tag' for #<#<Class:0x5cbe468>:0x5cbcb60>
```

what should I add or change to make it work ?

**UPDATE**
And here is my process_login function

```
def process_login
    if user=MyEmployee.authenticate(params[:fullname])
      session[:id]=user.id
      redirect_to session[:return_to]
    else
      flash[:error]='Login fails, unauthenticated user'
      redirect_to :action => 'login', :fullname=>params[:user][:fullname]
    end
  end
```

Comment: What does "Make it work" look like? Why do you have action set to process_login? Do you have a function in your controller named process_login? If so post it.

Comment: I edit it with an addition of process_login

Answer (score 0):

You're using a *very, very old* syntax there. `end_form_tag` was deprecated in Rails 2.

Use this syntax instead:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'process_login' do%>
  Username: <%= text_field "user", "fullname" %>&#x00A;
  Password: <%= password_field "user", "password" %>&#x00A;
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Whatever guide has you using `end_form_tag` is really old and shouldn't be used any more. I would recommend following the [Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org).